# TeamCity create installer using Installshield Limited Edition for VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, teamcity, installshield, teamcity-7.0, installshield-2012

I am using TeamCity to implement build automation.

Part of my build involves making an installer using Installshield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2012.

The build runs fine when the installer step is skipped, but fails with the following error when the installer is included;

> Compilation failed; error message is logged; process exited with code
>   1

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2012SpringLimited\InstallShield.targets(96, 3): OutputGroups item "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3e7f790aee82f740\TestProject\Trunk\Test.Project\obj\Release\Test.Project.xml" of "Test.Project.documentation files" does not appear to exist.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2012SpringLimited\InstallShield.targets(96, 3): OutputGroups item "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3e7f790aee82f740\TestProject\Trunk\Test.Content\obj\Release\Test.Content.xml" of "Test.Project.Content.documentation files" does not appear to exist.
Project TestProject\Trunk\Setup\Setup.isproj failed. 
Project TestProject\Trunk\Setup\Setup.isproj.metaproj failed. 
Project TestProject\Trunk\Test.Project.sln failed.
```

Both Test.Project.xml and Test.Content.xml exist in the proper location.

---

TeamCity 7.1.5 (build 24400)

Visual Studio Pro 2012 Update 2

InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my .vbproj files I had a checkbox named

"Generate XML documentation file" checked

Unchecking this box on all my projects fixed my problem